# How to fetch column values from database onto a Pop-up form for only those projects selected by user?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, popup

I am using `MySQL Database` under which I have a table named **`sponsors`** having following columns.

```
id | project_id | project_name | sector | duration | budget | location
```

Now, I have created a page in `php` on which a user can select multiple projects at a time by clicking on the checkbox as you can see in the image below :

[image: Multiple projects selection page]

After selecting the projects, when user clicks on submit, a pop-up form will appear like this :

[image: Pop-up form]

On which there should be the comma separated values of `project_id` (from the Database) of all the selected projects by user.

So far I've done this much coding :

```
 <!-- //CheckBOX -->
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check_id[]"
                            value="<?php $row["project_id"];?>"> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $data["project_id"]; ?>   </td>
 <td> <?php echo $data["project_name"]; ?> </td>
```

[See this](https://www.paste.org/92566) to have a view of full code.

So, my question is **How to fetch column values from database onto a Pop-up form for only those projects that have been checkbox selected by user** ?

How can I achieve that. I am open to accept any sensible solution in any language, but would prefer to have it in JavaScript or php .

Comment: Question, do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are adding the table-rows with a loop of some sort, and if so, you can assign the value of the key in your checkboxes `name` field, then use that on the other end to pull the matching `$data[]` value;

```
<?php foreach ($yourArray as $key => $data): ?>
<!-- //CheckBOX -->
 <td> <input type="checkbox" name="check_id[<?php echo $key; ?>]"
                            value="YES"> </td>
 <td> <?php echo $data["project_id"]; ?>   </td>
 <td> <?php echo $data["project_name"]; ?> </td>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then when the form is submitted you pull the key back and use it to retrieve the value in your original array.  It would look something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['check_id'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == 'YES') {
        $selectedRows[] = $yourArray[$key];
    }
}
```